# Making menu item active based on url and query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have some menu item in my application which are as below :

1. Statistics
2. Tax
3. Skills

Now when user click on any menu item I want to make it active like when user click on statistic I would like to make it active and this is how currently I am doing it and it is working fine.

**_Layout.cshtml**:

```
<div class="Menu @Html.IsSelected(actions: "Index", controllers: "Statistics", class: "active")" ><a href="/Statistics/Index">Stats</a></div>
<div class="Menu @Html.IsSelected(actions: "Index", controllers: "Tax", class: "active")"><a href="/Tax/Index">Tax</a></div>
<div class="Menu @Html.IsSelected(actions: "Index", controllers: "Skills", class: "active")"><a href="/Skills/Index">Skills</a></div>



public static string IsSelected(this HtmlHelper html, string controllers = "", string actions = "", string cssClass = null)
        {
            ViewContext viewContext = html.ViewContext;
            bool isChildAction = viewContext.Controller.ControllerContext.IsChildAction;

            if (isChildAction)
                viewContext = html.ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext;

            RouteValueDictionary routeValues = viewContext.RouteData.Values;
            string currentAction = routeValues["action"].ToString();
            string currentController = routeValues["controller"].ToString();


            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(actions))
                actions = currentAction;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(controllers))
                controllers = currentController;

            //for passing multiple comma seperated Action.
            //For Eg:class="@Html.IsSelected(actions: "List,Detail", controllers: "Default")"
            string[] acceptedActions = actions.Trim().Split(',').Distinct().Select(t=>t.ToLower().ToString()).ToArray();
            string[] acceptedControllers = controllers.Trim().Split(',').Distinct().Select(t=>t.ToLower().ToString()).ToArray();

            return acceptedActions.Contains(currentAction.ToLower()) && acceptedControllers.Contains(currentController.ToLower()) ?
                cssClass : String.Empty;
        }
```

But now I have 1 common page accessible from both statistics and tax page :

**Rank**

Url when user goes to this page from Statistics :

```
http://localhost:1231/Rank/Index?type=stats&Id=21
```

Url  when user goes to this page from Statistics :

```
http://localhost:1231/Rank/Index?type=Tax&Id=48
```

So I would like to make Statistics menu active when user goes on Rank page from Statistics page and make Tax menu item active when user goes on rank page from Tax page.

Comment: Its very unclear what your really trying to do with that extension method and at the very least it should be returning the whole html you want (i.e. the `<div>` and the `<a>` elements which you would use as (say) `@Html.MyLinkFor("Stats", "Index", "Statistics")`. At the moment your repeating code by including parameters for the `actionName` and `controllerName` in the extension method and then again in you manual `<a>` tag.

Comment: And why would you want multiple `<div>` elements to be given a `class="active"`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke:That extension method return active class for each menu item.Now what happens is suppose you are on statistics page then in that case that extension method will return active and in case of Tax and Skills it will return empty string

Comment: What do you mean _return active class for each menu item_? Are you saying that code adds `class-"active"` to all 3 `<div>` elements?

Comment: @StephenMuecke:Nope not all 3 menu items because when i will be on Statistics page then in my extension method i will get current controller and action method name from route dictionary and that will match my statistics and index action name which i am passing to this extension method.so in this way this will apply active class to only that menu item which user has clicked

Comment: Good - because you would have been wrong otherwise :). If that is what you trying to do, then teh code in your extension method is not the correct way to go about this, and you code can be simplified considerably (see the suggestions in my first comment). Ignoring the bit about the `Rank` page for the moment, what is the point of the _passing multiple comma seperated Action_ - why would you want more than one `<div>` to have `class="active"` (which is what the purpose of that code is)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke : But that extension method will just make only 1 menu item active based on route dictionary value.Like suppose i am on statistics page then only statistics menu item will be active and not tax and skills

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134728/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-learning).

Answer (score 1):

You're making this way too complicated. Try this instead:

```
@{ string url = null; }

@{ url = Url.Action("Index", "Statistics"); }
<div class="Menu @(url == Request.Url.AbsolutePath ? "active" : null)">
    <a href="@url">Stats</a>
</div>

@{ url = Url.Action("Index", "Tax"); }
<div class="Menu @(url == Request.Url.AbsolutePath ? "active" : null)">
    <a href="@url">Tax</a>
</div>

@{ url = Url.Action("Index", "Skills"); }
<div class="Menu @(url == Request.Url.AbsolutePath ? "active" : null)">
    <a href="@url">Skills</a>
</div>
```

In other words, all you need is a simple ternary to compare the URL of the link with the current URL. `Request.Url.AbsolutePath` is used so that query strings are ignored. Setting a `url` variable just prevents having to call `Url.Action` multiple times, keeping things DRY.

Comment: But when i will visit rank page from statistics page then how i will make statistics menu item active?

Comment: Well, that's a really poor way to handle indicating where the user came from. It would be better to have that indicated in the URL itself, i.e. `/stats/rank`, `tax/rank`, etc. However, you can just add a condition to the ternary: `url == Request.Url.AbsolutePath || Request["type"] == "stats"`

Comment: @Learning: it looks like you received a solid answer here. Would you consider accepting it? To accept answers that worked for you, click the tick/check icon to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, just like a trick

1. Create a `css` of `Active` and set whatever color you want to show active.
2. On selection of any of them, remove class from all, get what item is clicked. add class named `Active` to only that element.

Comment: I have call with active and everything and my method IsSelected is working fine but the only problem is with making statistics and tax menu item active when rank page is visited